# If statement using jQuery ':visible' not returning boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, visible

I have created a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/c2gjh43j/3/.  I am using the line

```
if ( !target.siblings("aside").is(":visible") ) {
```

to check whether the target's 'aside' sibling is not visible, but it always returns true, even after my javascript has shown the 'aside' element.  Because of this my else statement will not run. You can see that clicking on a box in the fiddle will show the hidden element but when it is visible, you should be able to click on the box and hide it.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post your "*[mcve]*" code in your question, don't just link to it and expect us to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you mixed your priorities maybe and having so much on your mind, you forgot to add the commands to "else" statement (hide and remove class). I also removed the "show" beneath this line:

```
$(this.resource).removeClass("active");
```

I modified your code and I hope this works like you want. The other files are intact, only the js file is modified as follows:

```
Services = {
    resource: "#resources-grid .resource",
    resourceTrigger: "#resources-grid .resource .full-link",
    description: ".description",
    init: function() {
        $(this.resourceTrigger).click(this.toggleResource.bind(this));
    },

    toggleResource: function(e) {
        $(this.resource).removeClass("active");

        var target = $(e.target);

        if ( !target.siblings("aside").is(":visible") ) {
            console.log("yes");

            // Edit START
            $("aside").hide();
            // Edit END

            target.siblings("aside").show();
            target.parents(".resource").addClass("active");
        } else {
            console.log("no");
            target.siblings("aside").hide();
            target.parents(".resource").removeClass("active");
        }
    },
}
Services.init();
```

As a side note, try to comment your code with tasks "To-do:" and indent your code.

Hope I helped you !

**Edit:**
Add this:

```
$("aside").hide();
```

before

```
target.siblings("aside").show();
```

Comment: your code is a step in the right direction, but notice what happens when you click on the second box with the first open.  Updated fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/c2gjh43j/4/.  I need the first box to close if it is clicked when open, but also if another box is clicked

Comment: True, I forgot to check for this. I will come back with a working code asap. It's night here and tomorrow I have to go to work, but tomorrow the latest I will post an update.